# Can't add custome error page in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Hi i'm trying in a thymeleaf project to add a custom error page by adding a 404.html page in templates.

But when i type localhost:8080/RandomUrl-doesn't-that-exist i have the standard error 404 message.

My config :

```html
#for Spring Boot 2.0
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
```

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

```html
Solution : don't remove whitelabel message in applications.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a generic `error` page in Thymeleaf, just add `error.html` file into the templates folder

like this --> `src/main/resources/templates/error.html`

but if you want to handle specific errors like `404`,

create `errors` page, then create `404.html` page inside of it.

like this --> `src/main/resources/templates/error/404.html`

Comment: That is weird, it must be a configuration issue then!

Comment: solved it, i added a line to remove whitelabel, it was causing the issue. I removed it.

Comment: is it this configuration `server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false`

Comment: If you solved, I suggest that you add the solution to your question, in order to benefit whoever have the same problem and got to this page.